# Gas boiler cuts out after being switched on

Tags: boiler

When I switch on our gas boiler (mynute he), it turns off after approximately 2 seconds.  Link to newer model here https://www.vokera.ie/homeowners/boilers/mynute-vhe-2/

I checked a radiator to see if air would come out and there doesn't seem to be an excess of air.  The water pressure is at 2 bar so no problem there.

This started after a local power outage where the boiler was unpowered for several hours.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have good input pressure from the water main?

Comment: my be a safety cutout not detecting a flame

Comment: I presume "mynute" is the make, what's the actual model number? What, exactly, do you mean by "switch on" and "it turns off" - does that refer to the burner lighting and immediately going out? Is that a pump that should be pushing the heated water? I know it's obvious to you, but the more detail you can edit into your question the easier it is to figure out from over here on the other side of the screen.

Comment: @spikey_richie yes, opened the water valve to increase to 2 bar.

Comment: Mynute he is the model https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.vokera.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2009/04/mynute-he-installation-and-servicing-manual.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwj4roqHvuvsAhWkURUIHbqoBosQFjAAegQIAxAB&usg=AOvVaw31wzb5VlkI8h892wGWTZba

Comment: The control board (tiny computer brain) may have been damaged by side effects of the power outage (surge spike either when it went out or when it came on.)

Comment: When lighting the pilot have you waited 30 seconds to a minute prior to turning the valve to on? Is the flame hitting the thermocouple?
Is the thermocouple in the flame or window on the sensor clean?